# CSS Hover and Javascript works on one page and not the other?

Tags: javascript, html, css

ok I had asked for some help on here getting a hover and click setup working for three images.

If you go to http://www.djcproductions.net/test.html you can see everything working perfectly.

However, when I copied and pasted the elements into the actual layout- it does not do the hover. I have stared at the code for at least six hours, moving things around, changing whatever I thought might be causing it and I just cannot figure it out. I have a feeling it is one of those things that I am just missing because I keep staring at it.

The contents loaded into the layout can be found at http://www.djcproductions.net

If anyone could look at the source code for these two pages and maybe see what I am doing wrong it would be appreciated more than you could possibly imagine- it is driving me insane.

Thanks!

****EDIT**** I checked this on another computer- in IE, the hover still does not work, but the three images display and swap on click. In chrome, only the web design and web hosting images display and the advertising image is nowhere to be found but the hover and click functions both work. Any ideas?

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure it's not working? Perhaps clear your cache and try refreshing your page?

Comment: Works for me as well in chrome and FF.

Comment: Works for me, too. What browser are you using?

Comment: I tried clearing the cache first because I figured that was my problem.  I am using Avant browser, but it is just a webshell for IE and I tested it in plain old IE as well. So everyone sees it working but me? That makes me feel better atleast, though a bit silly for playing with it for hours on end trying to fix what was not broken -.-

Comment: Both working on Windows 7 x64 Ultimate, Firefox 11.0.

Comment: Corbin, I could get it to *not* work by switching IE into quirks mode.  Maybe your browser has been placed in that mode for some reason.

Comment: How do I take it out of quirks mode?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are not using window.onload, that may be causing the problem... or use [jQuery .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 0):

IE may be switching to quirks mode, you can check this through the developer tools for IE (press <kbd>F12</kbd>).  If you're testing the page at an intranet URL, IE switches to compatibility mode by default, and that can cause quirks mode.  Avaya may also be switching IE to this mode.  If you add the right `meta` tag to your page, you can force a different document mode.  Try placing this in your page (you can specify a non-edge version as well):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: What does that tag do? I am unfamiliar with the "edge" element. Will that make it work in more than just IE? It really seems to display in each browser differently and I am not sure why

Comment: This article will help explain this meta tag and other browser rendering mode topics: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/beyonddoctype

Comment: Ah, thank you.  I fixed the hover problem by declaring the doctype, somehow I forgot to do that.  Now, I tried what you said, using that code out of curiosity to see if it would fix my current problem and it literally disassembled my website's layout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert (at all), but looking at your page, it appears that you're missing `<a href="pages/ad.html" target="slider">` for your ad link (~line 164 of your source code). Could that be why it doesn't appear?

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, I ended up redoing the entire page anyway at this point, that part is now functioning as I would like it to, all except the preloader for the images! Thank you though :)